# Azure DevOps: Group Rules

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-security

Organizational Settings -> Users -> Group Rules -> (Add a Group Rule)

Where does the list of "Azure DevOps Groups" populate from and is there a way to add additional groups to the list?

[image: Add group rule]

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/assign-access-levels-and-extensions-by-group-membership?view=azure-devops) it looks like it's built-in list and you can't change it:

> Group rules can also be used to add users to team projects and other specific groups, like Contributors, Readers, and Administrators.

You can open a Feature Request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) for an option to add some groups to there.

Comment: I think you're right it can't be changed (I at least can't find a way to change it); but what on that Docs page gives you that idea? Step #6 kind of glosses over what "Azure DevOps Groups" does.

Comment: The docs write literally "like .. .. .." without any info about add another groups, this is gave me the idea...

Comment: Yeah, that's probably not a good sign ;-). I filled out a Doc enhancement request for that page. I'm going to leave this question open for a bit longer in hopes that maybe someone from Microsoft will comment and confirm our suspicions. Thanks again!

Comment: @Doug a great idea!!

Comment: hi,Doug Currently, this is designed like this. You could submit a feature request in our Develop Community site. Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion. : )